# React Native not working with output in console.log

Tags: react-native

```
const [task, setTask] = useState()
const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([])


const handleAddTask = () => {
  setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
  setTask(null)
  console.log(task) <--
}

  return (
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
      <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Today's tasks</Text>
      <View style={styles.items}>
          <Task text={'Task 1'} />
          <Task text={'Task 2'} />
          <Task text={'Task 3'} />
          <Task text={'Task 4'} />
      </View>
    </View> 
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={"Write a task"} onChange={text => setTask(text)}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
            <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
);
```

I created a react native app using expo and I would like to use `console.log(xxx)` to display the result on the console. Any good suggestions where to open the console in order to view the log results?

Comment: provide your code here

Comment: Your code is not enough. Please add more code: where the `handleAddTask` is call?

Comment: Official link is here: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/logging/ . It may help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to change this lines:

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={"Write a task"} onChange={text => setTask(text)}/>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
```

TO:

```
<TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={"Write a task"} onChangeText={setTask}/>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handleAddTask}>
```